# Tengo un problema de comunicacion entre el BackEnd e Identity Server, el cliente no puede acceder al endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

Tengo una triada: apk (react native), identity server y un backend (api con .net core), el identity entrega bien el acces token y el ide token a la apk (lo veo en el terminal del identity) ... pero en el monento de hacer el request al backend desde la apk, al parecer este no puede verificar la identidad con el authority (identity server) y no puedo acceder al acces point.

el backend me registra este error en el terminal

[image: error mostrado por el BackEcnd]

he verificado q el ip del authority sea el correcto al igual q su puerto
alguien pudiera indicarme donde podria estar el problema?

Comment: Me parece que es porque no estás haciendo la petición via https

Comment: Dice "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure". Creo que el cliente no está aceptando el certificado del servidor. Pueden ser porque es un certificado autofirmado o porque está vencido.

Answer (score 0):

Como comentan anterior mente no estas trabajando sobre HTTPS, recuerda que todos tus recursos así como el cliente deben de realizar las peticiones vía  HTPPS.
En tu Api .NetCore puedes usar en el método Configure el Middleware

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

De igual forma cambia la url principal de las peticiones en tu cliente a `https://{miapi}`